# Calculate PE ratio of equal-weighted index

Tags: equities, index, valuation, earnings, ratio

I need to calculate `Price-to-Earnings Ratio (PE Ratio)` of an **Equal-weighted index**.

```
                                     Sum of market caps  
P/E for Market-cap Weighted index = -------------------
                                      Sum of Earnings 

                                       Sum of market caps         Shares1*Price1 + Shares2*Price2 + ... 
P/E for Equal Weighted index = ?? ---------------------------- OR -------------------------------------- 
                                 (Sum of Earnings/# of stocks)    Shares1*EPS1 + Shares2*EPS2 + ...
```

where Shares1, Shares2, etc are number of shares in the portfolio (replicating the index).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take [the (simple) harmonic mean](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/harmonicaverage.asp) of the P/E's of the stocks in the index given that it's an equal-weighted equity index.

Suppose you have $N$ stocks in the equal-weighted index. Then, using the harmonic mean formula, the index's P/E would be calculated as:

$$\text{P/E}_{\text{index}} = \dfrac{N}{\mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\text{P/E}_i}} \tag{1}$$

where $\text{P/E}_i$ is the P/E of stock $i$ and calculated as $\frac{M_i}{E_i}$ with $M_i$ being the stock $i$'s market cap and $E_i$ its earnings.

The logic behind the use of the harmonic mean can be explained by using the holding company analogy which I also used in [my answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/68325/47484) to another question about index P/E's.

Suppose the assets of a holding company $H$, whose market cap is $R_H$, comprise of $N$ stocks with equal weights. The holding company's earnings, $E_H$, would then be the sum of the earnings of the stocks, $E_i$, weighted by the holding company's respective ownership ratios, $x_i$, in each. Then, the holding company's P/E would be:

$$\begin{align}
\text{P/E}_{H} &= \dfrac{R_H}{E_H} \\
&= \dfrac{R_H}{\mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_iE_i}.
\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Assuming $M_i$ again denotes the market cap of the stock $i$, we can figure out $x_i$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
x_iM_i &= \dfrac{R_H}{N} \\
x_i &= \dfrac{R_H}{NM_i}. \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Substituting (3) into (2), we find:

$$\begin{align}
\text{P/E}_{H}
&= \dfrac{R_h}{\mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left(\dfrac{R_H}{NM_i}\right)E_i} \\
&= \dfrac{R_H}{\dfrac{R_H}{N} \mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left(\dfrac{1}{M_i}\right)E_i} \\
&= \dfrac{N}{\mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{E_i}{M_i}} \\
&= \dfrac{N}{\mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{\frac{M_i}{E_i}}} \\
&= \dfrac{N}{\mathop {\sum}\limits_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\text{P/E}_i}}
\tag{4}\end{align}$$

which is the same as the equation (1).